# Почему в образе, который создаю, не создается пользователь?

Tags: docker

Вот мой Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash chc || echo "User creation failed"

USER chc
WORKDIR /home/chc
```

Вот результат сборки:

```
Step 3/5 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash chc || echo "User creation failed"
---> Running in 6def765288f6
Removing intermediate container 6def765288f6
---> b760fa411e30
Step 4/5 : USER chc
---> Running in 09a2068f18d7
Removing intermediate container 09a2068f18d7
---> f9b5cdae2f64
Step 5/5 : WORKDIR /home/chc
---> Running in f0889357344c
Removing intermediate container f0889357344c
---> 1eeab3145258
Successfully built 1eeab3145258
```

Вот результат команды: `docker images -a`

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>       <none>    1eeab3145258   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    f9b5cdae2f64   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    b760fa411e30   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    353d3971a178   9 minutes ago   200MB
ubuntu       latest    e34e831650c1   7 days ago      77.9MB
```

Вот запуск образа ubuntu: `docker run -it ubuntu`:

```
root@c1dc8a7ccd60:/#
```

А вот попытка переключить юзера:

```
root@c1dc8a7ccd60:/# su - chc
su: user chc does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields
```

Я кое-что узнал, если запустить это: `Successfully built 1eeab3145258` то есть:

```
docker run -i -t 1eeab3145258
```

То, получаю своего нового юзера:

```
chc@6a2cc5c466b1:~$
```

И это "`1eeab3145258`" есть в списке образов:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>       <none>   "1eeab3145258"   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    f9b5cdae2f64   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    b760fa411e30   9 minutes ago   201MB
<none>       <none>    353d3971a178   9 minutes ago   200MB
ubuntu       latest    e34e831650c1   7 days ago      77.9MB
```

Не могу понять в чем же дело! Я же собираю образ на основе образа **ubuntu**! А если запустить этот образ, то нет git'a, нет юзера, и пакеты не обновляются...
Где я ошибаюсь, пожалуйста, подскажите, я уже 3 часа ломаю мозги...

Comment: `docker run -it ubuntu` запускает оригинальный образ

Comment: Тебе надо вызывать `docker build ... -t myubuntu` и после этого ты сможешь вызывать `docker run -it myubuntu`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, если честно не очень понял, можно подробнее ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы взяли образ `ubuntu` и добавили в него git и своего пользователя. Сам образ `ubuntu` не изменился, все ваши добавления отправились в образ с хеш кодом `1eeab3145258`.

Вы можете присвоить удобное имя через опцию `-t NAME` команды `docker build`. Например

```
docker build -t chc-ubuntu .
```

В результате у вас появится образ с именем `chc-ubuntu`. Его можно запустить по имени

```
docker run --rm -it chc-ubuntu
```

Проверьте сами - в этом запущенном контейнере есть и git, и ваш пользователь.

PS. Ключ `--rm` удаляет контейнер после того, как он отработает.  Это часто делается для контейнеров, запущенных через `-it`, чтобы сбросить состояние и при следующем запуске снова был чистый контейнер без предистории.